# Class not found error, but class is in JAR file on classpath

Tags: java, classpath

When calling a Java class from command line Java can't find the executable class, even though it's in a JAR file on the class path.  I was getting this from a call within a Python script, but the same behavior happens on command line (DOS on Windows).  Can anyone advise?

```
c:\nco> java -mx1200m -cp C:\tmp\lib\indices-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar nidis.indices.GriddedIndexCalculator 

Error: Could not find or load main class nidis.indices.GriddedIndexCalculator

c:\nco> jar -tf C:\tmp\lib\indices-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar | find "GriddedIndexCalculator"

nidis/indices/GriddedIndexCalculator.class
```

Comment: does this class have the main method?

Comment: why not java -jar C:\tmp\lib\indices-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar ?

Comment: Yes, there is a main method in the class.  There are other JARs on the classpath, the single JAR file in question is shown for brevity only.

Answer (score 2):

Java omits the classpath variable when you run it with `java -jar` due to security reasons.

The solution is to define the dependencies in the `Class-Path:` attribute of your `MANIFEST.MF` file.